# Android: here.com's getMapPackages listener never catches onGetMapPackagesComplete event

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps

Using here.com proprietary code I'm trying to get the list of map packages so that I'll hopefuly know a country ID I'm interested in so I'm using the following code to load all map packages:

`MapLoader mapLoader = MapLoader.getInstance();
 mapLoader.addListener(mapLoaderListener);
 boolean packagesgotten=mapLoader.getMapPackages();`

Now the maploaderlistener is supposed to catch the event when this download is complete. So I put some code to output the packages in the onGetMapPackagesComplete method of the listener but it never gets called. No error, nothing. This code is in an AsyncTask as network requests require that.

Comment: any progress concerning this?

Comment: @rashad.z No, and there won't be as the project is dropped.